# Call Bootbox.js from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I need way to run bootbox I have next code:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x1 = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
if (x1 == null || x1 == "") {
       alert("Please Enter name"); // I WANT CALL Bootboxjs HERE
        return false;
    }
}
 </script>
```

So I want replace standard javascript alert with this:

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
  Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
```

I tried to paste `botbox.alert`in javascript function but don't work.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is replace the default javascript alert method

This feature is available in all browser without any kind of problem, just override the alert method with

```
window.alert = function(message){
    bootbox.alert(message, function() {
         // execute a predefined callback
    });
}
// and call like 

alert("Hello world"); // shows bootbox alert
```

and if you want to include the callback :

```
// include this before any alert call is executed in any script
window.alert = function(message,callback){
    bootbox.alert(message, callback);
}
// and call like 

alert("Hello world",function(){
  console.log("custom callback");
}); // shows bootbox alert
```